# regex \p{L} problems

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

im using this for my Validation:

```
$space = "[:blank:]";
$number = "0-9";
$letter = "\p{L}"; 
$specialchar = "-_.:!='\/&*%+,()";
...
$default = "/^[".$space.$number.$letter.$specialchar."]*$/";
if (!preg_match($all, $input)){
                $error = true;
}
```

The Problem i have is:
all is working except "ü"... "Ü" is but "ü" not and i dont know why?
\p{L} should accept all letters and special letters... i dont get it why its not working :(

 anyone an idea what i can do?

The data i try to validate is a POST Value from a registration FORM

// p.s. if im using \p{L}ü i get an error like this:

```
 Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 23 in...
```

Comment: I guess the problem is the encoding. Make sure the encoding of the input matches the encoding used by your PCRE library (check the compilation mode).

Comment: that might be the problem, im working with a "smaller" solution now, im just allowing UTF-8 letters now, must be good enough thx all

Answer (score 4):

Escape the dash:

```
$specialchar = "\-_.:!='\/&*%+,()";
#        here __^
```

Also add the `/u` modifier for unicode matching:

```
$default = "/^[".$space.$number.$letter.$specialchar_def."]*$/u";
#                                                      here __^
```

**Test:**

```
$space = "[:blank:]";
$number = "0-9";
$letter = "\p{L}"; 
$specialchar = "\-_.:!='\/&*%+,()";
$default = "/^[".$space.$number.$letter.$specialchar."]*$/u";
//                  wrong variable name ^^^^^^^^^^^^ in your example.
$input = 'üÜ is but ';
if (!preg_match($default, $input)){
    echo "KO\n";
} else {
    echo "OK\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
OK
```

Comment: yep forgot that and did it allready but the "ü" still not working

Comment: @xQp: Yes, i'm sure. It works well for me. See my edit

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the position that the hyphen is placed in. Within a character class you can place a hyphen as the first or last character in the range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it in order to add it to your class.

```
$specialchar = "_.:!='\/&*%+,()-";
```

Also you need to add the `u` (Unicode) modifier to your regular expression. This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE and pattern strings are treated as (**UTF-8**) and you have the wrong variable in the pattern.

```
$default = "/^[".$space.$number.$letter.$specialchar."]*$/u";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-` is a special character in character class used to specify a range of character. When you construct the regex by string concatenation, it is recommended that you escape it `\-`.

Including the fix above, there is another problem in `"\-_.:!='\/&*%+,()"`. Do you want to include `\` and `/`? Or only one of them?

If you want to include both, you should specify it as `"\-_.:!='\\\\\/&*%+,()"`.

If you don't want to escape `/`, you can replace your separator `/` in the construction of `$default` to something not used in your regex, for example `~`. In that case, the list of special character will have one less `\`: `"\-_.:!='\\\\/&*%+,()"`.

Comment: thx for the help but pls guys i dont have any trouble with that specialchars the only one i have is with \p{L} -> "ü" not working and trouble with page if i try to validate "ü"

Comment: @xQp: Can you copy and paste umlaut u from the page? If it contains combining mark, you might need to change your regex to allow it.

Comment: Dont know what exactly you mean with that, but "ü" is excactly how its written on the page i dont think i need any combining mark for it, but i guess \p{L} is not working with that page

Comment: its working if i replace \p{L} with "a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜßé" 
not all i wanted to allow but i think i need to work with this

Comment: @xQp: How do you get your data? What function did you use? Can you edit your question to include that information?

Comment: i did, its from an registration FORM im getting it via POST value